# DateTime Series Issue PineScript

Tags: datetime, pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm working to fill an array with High/Low pivot points of the "Previous Trading Day", but I'm facing an issue in terms of the time series (second section below!). I'm not sure if that PineScript's bug or my misunderstanding of how are the time-series functions working!! Please Help, very organize details.

Calling for current Trading Day, then selected the regular session ( No issues in this part )

```
//------------------ Selected Day of Trading
//Start Day
Start_Period= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2020, 12, 09, 00, 00, 00)
//End Day
End_Period  = timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2020, 12, 09, 23, 59, 59)

//------------------ Filtring Session
// Regular Session
t_reg   = time("1440", session.regular)
```

---

The issue only in this coding box.

Pine script would not recognize the result of `Change_Time`

```
// Detect the change of time between selected day trading and most recent day trading (t-t[1])
Change_Time = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1440", change(time)) 
FunYesterday()=>
    if time >= Start_Period-Change_Time and time <= End_Period-Change_Time and t_reg
        [pivothigh(close, 3, 2), pivotlow(close, 3, 2)]
```

However, if I substitute the `security` function of `Change_time= 60*60*24*1000`will work fine!!, but I tried to avoid this method because of time deference on weekends, and other holidays.

---

Final Section find Pivot and Create Array ( No issues in this part )

```
//------------------ Pivot point at 15 min. 
[ph2, pl2] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", FunYesterday(), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
ph2_filter= ph2 == ph2[1]?na:ph2
pl2_filter= pl2 == pl2[1]?na:pl2

//------------------ Array Part
var a = array.new_float()
if (not na(ph2_filter))
    array.push(a,ph2_filter)
else if (not na(pl2_filter))
    array.push(a,pl2_filter)


if barstate.islast and array.size(a)>0
        
    y=label.new(bar_index, close, "Initial\na: " + tostring(a))
    label.delete(y[1])
```

I'm very open if you have any other idea to import data from the most recent trading day only!!. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here. On what timeframe would your chart be? I see that you're looking for 15min pivot points, so I assume a timeframe lower than 15min?

Comment: Sorry. The timeframe is not an issue in my case. I'm trying to get pivots of the most recent trading day. For example, Today is Friday, so I want to collect pivots into an array of Thursday at 15 min TimeFrame. 
Check the second box of my coding,  specifically at `Change_Time` variable. I don't understand why the variable wouldn't give an output when I used it inside the created function `FunYesterday()`
Let me know if you have you didn't get it.

Comment: Then you will need to use a main timeframe of 15min or lower, because in Pine script you can retrieve data from higher timeframes, but not for lower timeframes.

Comment: I'm using a lower timeframe, but it doesn't work!. I don't think you got my question. Let me ask you this question, what do you expect output from this statement. `Change_Time = security(syminfo.tickerid, "1440", change(time)) `

Comment: It will give the difference in UNIX time between current trading and most recent trading day to be `Change_Time` => 86400000mS for 0 day-off, `Change_Time` => 86400000x2 mS for one day-off,  `Change_Time` => 86400000mSx3 for two days off like weekend.

Comment: If I add that variable inside a function  `FunYesterday()=> if time >= Start_Period-Change_Time and time <= End_Period-Change_Time and t_reg`

Comment: Please run the script from your side, and you'll get the idea!. It's not related to the timeframe at all.

Comment: Results obtained with `security()` will depend, among other things, on the relationship between the chart's resolution and the resolution you are using in your `security()` calls. So to answer your question, we need to know the resolution of the chart from which you are making your `security()` calls at 15min and 1440min.

Comment: Got it, means impossible to do it in that way. This leading me to this question.
From your experience, Is there an idea to store pivots data of the previous day trading, and put them inside an array to carry those points to the current day trading?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65306165/how-to-store-data-pivots-from-previous-trading-day-and-draw-them-as-levels-on