# How to store data (pivots) from previous trading day, and draw them as levels on current today trading session?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

Trying to find some way to store pivots data of the previous day trading, and put them inside an array to carry those points to the current day trading for drawing them as line levels.

---

### For example, $AAPL stock.

On Tuesday (yesterday), recorded pivots points at these levels [100.2, 100.3, 100.5] at 15-min timeframe.

On Wednesday (today), I'm looking to draw Support/Resistance lines based on selected pivots [100.2, 100.3, 100.5] from the previous day of trading.

I've already done it in python, but I couldn't find a successful method capable of pine script.

====================================================

### To PinseScript Response #1

I already tried this method before, but unfortunately, it didn't work inside a 15-min security function. It seems the security didn't recognize the result of `change(time('D'))`, but when I plot the `change(time('D'))`, it gives the result. [Check image description below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0dgW.png)

Again,

1. The output of `change(time('D'))` is not recognized by PineScript, if I use it inside a security function.
2. The PineScript Plotted the output `change(time('D'))` successfully. Check image bellow.

============================================

### To PinseScript Response #2

here's my full code, the change(time('D')) insdie function `FunYesterday()` below

```
//------------------ Select Day of Trading
Start_Period= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2020, 12, 09, 00, 00, 00) //Start Day
End_Period  = timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2020, 12, 09, 23, 59, 59) //End Day


//------------------ Filtring Session
t_reg   = time("1440", session.regular)  // Regular Session
t_ext   = time("1440", session.extended) // Extended Session
// Brackets the time [ Start Day --- To ----- End Day] 
T_ext   = time >= Start_Period and time <= End_Period and t_ext


// Build a function to detect the change of time between current day-trading and most recent day trading (t-t[1])

FunYesterday()=>
    Change_Time         = iff(T_ext == true, change(time("1D")), na) 
    Change_Time_Update  = fixnan(Change_Time <= 0? na: Change_Time)
    Change_Time_Update2 = iff(T_ext == true, Change_Time_Update, na)

    if time >= Start_Period-Change_Time_Update2 and time <= End_Period-Change_Time_Update2 and t_reg
        [pivothigh(close, 3, 2), pivotlow(close, 3, 2)]


//------------------ Pivot point at 15 min. 
[ph2, pl2] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", FunYesterday(), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
ph2_filter= ph2 == ph2[1]?na:ph2
pl2_filter= pl2 == pl2[1]?na:pl2

//------------------ Array Part
var a = array.new_float()
if (not na(ph2_filter))
    array.push(a,ph2_filter)
else if (not na(pl2_filter))
    array.push(a,pl2_filter)


if barstate.islast and array.size(a)>0
        
    y=label.new(bar_index, close, "Initial\na: " + tostring(a))
    label.delete(y[1])
```

Comment: What chart resolution are you looking to run your script from?

Comment: The script resolution should be at 15 min, and the chart resolution 5 min for the timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

#### Part 1

Provided you are running the chart on a < 15min resolution, the best way would be to maintain queues of pivot values using arrays and clear the arrays on `change(time("D"))` so they reset every day.

See the [usrman on arrays](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Arrays.html#using-an-array-as-a-queue) for an example of queue handling.

#### Part 2

`change(time("D"))` is meant to be detected at the chart's resolution:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
newDay = change(time("D"))
plotchar(newDay, "newDay", "►", location.top, size = size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work inside a 'security' function, but I'm able to plot the result. Kindly, could you check the update to my question above?. Thank you

Comment: See "Part 2" in my answer.

Comment: There's no problem to use `change(time('D'))` in plotting,  the issue is using the output of `change(time('D'))` in coding script, the PineScript doesn't recognize for boolean. Check my full code updated in the post under "To PinseScript Response #2"

Comment: Many functions require pre-evaluation before entry in conditional blocks. You need to take this into account when structuring Pine code: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#why-do-some-functions-and-built-ins-evaluate-incorrectly-in-if-or-ternary--blocks

Comment: I don't imagine how poor am I???. Working so hard in something that can't be solved in this form. I'll try some algorithm ideas to solve it! Thank you.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up like that ) We are all learning all the time.